# Switching databases as Azure Project Develops, but Azure Website Keeps pointing to Linked resource

Tags: entity-framework, azure

I think I may be missing something and hope you can advise

I have been developing a project using VS2013 with EF6. I use Visual Studio each time I want to deploy the latest version of the system to my Azure Website.

The Azure Website has a linked database resource (SQL Azure database).

This has been going great. However, yesterday I decided to create a Virtual Machine and move the SQL database to a dedicated Azure Virtual Machine. So I did this and now I have a new database as well as the old linked resource one

So, i'm ready to publish the APP and set the new database settings on the VM.

I changed the connection string in the publish wizard and published being sure to have the right settings, i.e. use this connection string at runtime and execute code first migrations etc

However, it took me a while to realise that the APP on the cloud server I just published too is still pointing to the OLD linked resource Azure database

I'm not sure what else I have to do to, I thought it was only about changing the publish setting for the database connection string

Am I missing something, should I delete the linked resource in the Azure Website settings, if i do would that make it work. Just weird because like I say i'm publishing the site again with new settings, or does Azure read the portals publish settings and somehow overidde what I want it to point to database wise

Please advise, many thanks

John

PS I can connect fine to the new database from my local management studio. I have no errors i'm just not sure how to tell Azure to use the connect string in publish profile other than what i am doing

Answer (score 0):

The "linked resource" in the Windows Azure management portal should have no impact on your application's functionality.  It is really just a way to help you understand / visualize the resources your application is using.

Comment: I see, I just need to figure out how to force the website to point at the new VM based Database rather than the SQL Azure one. I would have thought it was all about the connection string in the publish